# Nginx location redirect to destination URL obtained from a different server

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

In my current scenario there are a dozen domains with a PHP redirect script set up on them that obtains the destination URL from a SQL database based on the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] parameter passed in the URL initially requested by the User.

NginX is configured like this on each of these servers (which we'll call *Domains_A/B/C*):

```
        location /r/ {
            rewrite ^/r/(.*)$ /r/index.php?$1;
        }
```

So the request goes like User > Domains_A/B/C > Destination URL

But what I would like is to not have to duplicate the PHP redirect script and keep this script on a single domain. This may be obtained by doing something like this:

*Domains_A/B/C*

```
        location /r/ {
            rewrite ^/r/(.*)$ https://Domain_X/r/index.php?$1;
        }
```

*Domain_X (with PHP redirect script)*

```
        location /r/ {
            rewrite ^/r/(.*)$ /r/index.php?$1;
        }
```

But this multiplies the redirects as User > Domain_A/B/C > Domain_X (with PHP redirect script) > Destination URL. And also the Referer sent to Destination URL is Domain_X which is something I am trying to avoid.

I would like to not multiply the redirects and to keep *Domains_A/B/C* as the Referer too. As in have NginX obtain the destination URL from Domain_X when Domains_A/B/C are accessed and point the redirect directly at the Destination URL from *Domains_A/B/C*.

Something along these lines on *Domains_A/B/C*:

```
        location /r/ {
            set Destination_URL get from https://Domain_X/r/index.php?$1;
            rewrite ^/r/(.*)$ Destination_URL;
        }
```

Is this possible? I was not able to find a solution yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate the PHP script"? You only need one copy of the script. You do not have to do any of this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton of course I didn't have to do any of this, but all the same I did not know any other way, that was the motivation behind the question. See the accepted answer.

Comment: You don't have to do that either. Just call the PHP script directly.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The redirect needs to happen on some domains A/B/C (as in the user's browser needs to see _only_ the domains A/B/C), but the redirect URL has to be obtained from the PHP script which resides on a different server on domain X (the domain X has to remain hidden from the user). If I call the script directly on domain X, the redirect happens on that server and that is not the desired outcome. Maybe I do not understand something fully, if that is the case, please give me some more information.

Comment: OK, I missed the detail where you moved the PHP script to another server. I don't see that in your question. In that case you can't run it directly anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `proxy_pass` the request to the domain that has the redirect script:

On *Domains_A/B/C*:

```
location /r/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass https://Domain_X/r/index.php?$1;
}
```

Or (in my installations it worked only like this)

```
location ~ ^/r/(.*)$ {
    proxy_set_header Host PHP_SCRIPT_DOMAIN_NAME;
    proxy_pass https://PHP_SCRIPT_DOMAIN_IP:443/r/index.php?$1;
}
```

And on *Domain_X* (which has the PHP script).

```
location /r/ {
    rewrite ^/r/(.*)$ /r/index.php?$1;
}
```

Comment: This worked with some variations, thank you very much! I sent the edits I made in case you want to include them in your answer, as I think they add some value.